# How to plot 2D object in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to create an animation in which a box will move on a specified track.

Is there way to accomplish this task in python?
Also is there boolean plot function in matplotlib which can allow one to explicitly draw pixels?

Comment: try `pygame` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to adapt from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921313/matplotlib-animation-moving-square) (from @unutbu). The following code builds a square trajectory and moves a rectangle with it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib import animation

# Building a possible trajectory
x = np.hstack((np.linspace(-5, 5, 50), np.ones(50)*5, np.linspace(5, -5, 50), np.ones(50)*-5))
y = np.hstack((np.ones(50)*-5, np.linspace(-5, 5, 50), np.ones(50)*5, np.linspace(5, -5, 50)))

yaw = [0.0, 0.5, 1.3]
fig = plt.figure()
plt.axis('equal')
plt.grid()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Adding a simple plot for trajectory (initial coordinate of rectangle)
ax.plot([-5, 5, 5, -5, -5], [-5, -5, 5, 5, -5], color="grey", linestyle="--")

ax.set_xlim(-10, 10)
ax.set_ylim(-10, 10)

patch = patches.Rectangle((0, 0), 0, 0, fc='y')

def init():
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    return patch,

def animate(i):
    patch.set_width(1.2)
    patch.set_height(1.0)
    patch.set_xy([x[i], y[i]])
    return patch,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                               init_func=init,
                               frames=len(x),
                               interval=50,
                               blit=True)
plt.show()
```

, the result is this (well just a screenshot, its actually animated):

[image: Square animation in matplotlib]

As for your other question, matplotlib is not pixel based so I don't think you have a (easy) way of drawing just one pixel. Depending on your objective you light want to consider using the well supported [image](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html) api in matplotlib to provide you with customized backgrounds. So you would be drawing in arrays that would be parsed to the screen by matplotlib.